# I mistakenly closed a direct message window on Slack. How can I re-open it?

Tags: slack

I mistakenly closed a direct message window on Slack. How can I re-open it?

I clicked here:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just re-open a direct message with the same person. The conversation history will still be there.

On the same screen where you can start (or find) a direct conversation, there should be a list of recently active conversations. If you've forgotten which conversation you've closed you should be able to find it there.

Answer (score 3):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, enter the name of your contact and it should appear on the sidebar again.

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to reopen a conversation with **multiple participants**... I managed to do it by simply searching for some words I remembered from that conversation - apparently the search goes through removed conversations also.

Answer (score -1):

Just beside Direct Message you see three dots, click on it
then click on Browse DMs, then find for the person you removed
click on it :)